# Integers or Floats conversion to Binary (signed or unsigned)

Tags: python, math, binary, type-conversion

Any tips to correct this?
Example;
Enter a float number: -34.5
Binary: 1101 1110.1 #-33.5
The output is incorrect,
Because:
1   1 0  1 1 1 1 0 1
-128+64+0+16+8+4+2+0+0.5= -33.5

The output should be:
1101 1101.1 #-34.5

Because:
1  1  0 1  1 1 0 1.1
-128+64+0+16+8+4+0+1+.5 = -34.5

```
def twos_complement(binary):

    complement = ''.join('1' if bit == '0' else '0' if bit == '1' else bit for bit in binary)

    carry = 1

    result = ''

    for bit in complement[::-1]:      

        if bit == '1' and carry == 1:

            result += '0'

        elif bit == '0' and carry == 1:

            result += '1'

            carry = 0

        else:

            result += bit

    return result[::-1]



def integer_to_binary(integer):

    num_bits = integer.bit_length()

    num_bits = max(num_bits, 8)



    if integer >= 0:

        binary_value = bin(integer)[2:].zfill(num_bits)

        binary_value = ('0' * 4) + binary_value

        binary_value = ' '.join(binary_value[max(0, i - 4):i][::-1] for i in range(len(binary_value), 0, -4))

        return binary_value[::-1]

    elif 0 > integer >= -128:

        binary_value = bin((1 << num_bits) + integer & ((1 << num_bits) - 1))[2:].zfill(num_bits)

        binary_value = ('1' * 4) + binary_value

        binary_value = ' '.join(binary_value[max(0, i - 4):i][::-1] for i in range(len(binary_value), 0, -4))

        return binary_value[::-1]

    elif integer <= -129:

        binary_value = bin(integer)[3:].zfill(num_bits)

        binary_value = ('1' * 4) + twos_complement(binary_value)

        binary_value = ' '.join(binary_value[max(0, i - 4):i][::-1] for i in range(len(binary_value), 0, -4))

        return binary_value[::-1]



def float_to_binary(mixed):

    integer_part, decimal_part = str(mixed).split('.')

    binary_integer_part = integer_to_binary(int(integer_part))



    binary_decimal_part = ''

    if decimal_part != '0':

        decimal_part = '0.' + decimal_part

        decimal = float(decimal_part)

        while decimal != 0:

            decimal *= 2

            binary_decimal_part += str(int(decimal))

            decimal -= int(decimal)



    result = binary_integer_part + '.' + binary_decimal_part

    return result



input = float(input("Enter a float number: "))

result = float_to_binary(input)

print("Binary:", result)
```

I split the integer and decimals, then the integer part will be converted to binary by using it as an argument to the integer_to_binary function.
But the decimal part is converted to binary by repeatedly multiplying it by 2 and taking the integer part of the result.

My code doesn't have incorrect problem, if the expected output is integer(negative or positive) and float(positive only).
The problem only arise if the expected output is float and also negative.

What i want is, if the input is negative float. The output should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, first of all, I tried to debug your code, which honestly wasn't that easy with all those generator expressions like `(binary_value[max(0, i - 4):i][::-1] for i in range(len(binary_value), 0, -4))` or uncommented bitwise operators like this nasty expression `bin((1 << num_bits) + integer & ((1 << num_bits) - 1))`
Plus I really think your code can be much more simplified too, for example when I kept debugging for multiple test cases the only time the `twos_complement(binary_value)` was called is when `integer <= -129` and the passed argument was a string with only 0s and 1s so the first generator expression in the definition `def twos_complement(binary)` could be `complement = ''.join('1' if bit == '0' else '0' if bit == '1' for bit in binary)`and still I think this approach is much more difficult, after all there's a much more elegant way  to get 2's complement instead of doing 1's complement and adding 1 which you can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Working_from_LSB_towards_MSB)
And Now finally to answer your question, the mistake you made in code is that you took **the integer part = -34** (for `input = -34.5`) and then get its `binary_integer_part` and then took **decimal part = 0.5** and get its `binary_decimal_part`, but in the end you concatenate both strings and return result which definitely, result in this case will be if converted to decimal equal to = **integer part + decimal_part** **= -34 + 0.5 = -33.5** . So with the code you provided for example you can get -34.5 in the format you're looking for if `input = -35.5` since result will be = -35 + 0.5 = -34.5 which I tried and gives desired output. Hope I answered your concern :)